# GeoWebCache (GWC) "crashes" while seeding Tiles from large orthoimage (TIF; >10GB, 1cm GSD) in Azure BlobStorage

Tags: tiles, geowebcache, azure

Since three weeks we try to handle our **large orthoimages** (output agisoft/drones) in **Geoserver**. The orthoimages are approximately 10-15GB and have a ground sampling distance of 1cm. We have to host the images in UTM (**EPSG: 32632/32633**) and are not able to use a standard tile epsg (e.g. web mercator,etc.)

Therefor we created a gridset in UTM which works fine and also the tiling works fine with smaller geotiffs (~3-4GB). But trying to cache a monster (15GB TIF) will bust our system:

Now to our system:
We have a F16sv2 (16cores, 32GB Ram and Azure Files Disk) for our **Geoserver in Azure** for our tiles we connected the **BlobStorage** with the **Plugin** (works fine, too)

We tried different parameter of metatiling, different heap memory sizes of geoserver/gwc already -but it crashed!

So what actually happens...first it runs like hell! Either using 1 oder 14 treads! After the first minute we reach 10.000 Tiles of 130.000 Tiles...after 2 Minutes 17.000....and after a **while it gets slower and slower and slower**...actually after 2 hours it creates 1 tile per 30 minutes. The CPU usage is at 100%. The memory is normal.

The only way to stop this, is to delete the pod in our kubernetes service - just KILL it :-)

Has anywho have the same issues? We think yout using MapProxy instead and parallelize the seeding processes..

```
25 Nov 08:27:55 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException http://_______._________.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts
25 Nov 08:27:55 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Comment: You need to split the geotif into tiles, and possibly a pyramid, before you add it to geoserver. If you continue to have issues then you might need to switch to a supported blob store or fix the azure one.

Comment: Please add gdalinfo report about the 15 GB image. Is is tiled? Does it have overviews?

Comment: You might benefit from watching this [video](https://av.tib.eu/media/20401)

Comment: thanks for the VIDEO...

Answer (score 0):

we work with internal pyramids (until < 265pix)...here is an sample: Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: ..........\ortho.tif
Size is 231817, 259664
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (434801.428173321008217,5299382.361199897713959)
Pixel Size = (0.011175270647893,-0.011175270647894)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=LZW
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  434801.428, 5299382.361) (  8d 7'42.90"E, 47d50'40.12"N)
Lower Left  (  434801.428, 5296480.546) (  8d 7'44.48"E, 47d49' 6.14"N)
Upper Right (  437392.046, 5299382.361) (  8d 9'47.54"E, 47d50'41.05"N)
Lower Right (  437392.046, 5296480.546) (  8d 9'49.05"E, 47d49' 7.06"N)
Center      (  436096.737, 5297931.453) (  8d 8'45.99"E, 47d49'53.60"N)
Band 1 Block=231817x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Overviews: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Unit Type: metre
Band 2 Block=231817x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Overviews: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Unit Type: metre
Band 3 Block=231817x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Overviews: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Unit Type: metre
Band 4 Block=231817x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
Overviews: 115909x129832, 57955x64916, 28978x32458, 14489x16229, 7245x8115, 3623x4058, 1812x2029, 906x1015, 453x508, 227x254
Unit Type: metre

Answer (score 0):

**" then you might need to switch to a supported blob store or fix the azure one."** - do you mean we should switch to S3?

What is a supported blob sore?

**"split the geotif into tiles"** . what do you mean exactly? Shall we split the one GEOTIF into several single tifs? And publish the huge data as a group layer?

thanks
alex